# Merge two git branch with different folder names

Tags: git, git-merge

There are two branches in my project: R1 and OPE

Original folder structure of both the branches was:

```
dev-core/projectX/java-files
```

Now we started working on OPE branch and meanwhile root folder in R1 branch was renamed from dev-core to core. 
Now folder structure of R1 branch is:

```
core/projectX/java-files
```

and folder structure of OPE branch is:

```
dev-core/projectX/java-files
```

I have to merge changes of R1 branch in my OPE branch.
Now if I do a simple `git merge R1`, git is creating a dev-core folder in R1 branch and duplicating all the files in it.

I tried to rename folders in OPE by using `git mv` and then tried doing `git merge R1`, it is giving me following message for almost all files:

```
CONFLICT (rename/delete): core/projectX/path/to/java/file deleted in R1
  and renamed in HEAD. Version HEAD of core/projectX/path/to/java/file
  left in tree.
```

Now when I am checking the file and looking for conflicts (by searching for symbol `<<<`) I am not able find any conflicts. Can anyone please explain me what is happening here and how can I fix this?

Note: I used `--no-commit` option while merging.

### More Info

This is how I did the merge:

```
git checkout -b OPE origin/OPE
git checkout -b R1 origin/R1
git checkout OPE
git mv dev-core core
git merge R1
```

Here is my understanding of whats happening:
Lets say if there is a file `dev-core/projectX/file1`. I made some changes to this file in my `OPE branch` and committed it. Now somebody else made some change in `core/projectX/file1` in `R1 branch`. Now when I'll merge there are two possibilities:

1. Either git will merge both versions of file1 and will show me the conflict using <<<<<
2. OR git will sense that file1 is renamed from dev-core/projectX/file1 to core/projectX/file1 and will let me keep my file and will discard the changes from R1 branch file If I am correct then 2nd scenarios is my case and this might cause me loss of imp code Plz correct me if I'm wrong.

I tested renaming folders in git and my understanding was wrong. :( git detects folder renaming and will merge smartly. Now I have to figure out problem in my case.

Ahaaa I found my mistake, git is smart and I tried to be oversmart ;) All I had to do was `git merge` me doing `git mv dev-core core` added hell lot of complexity and caused lot of trouble :P

Comment: Your steps for merging look ok to me. Updating my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem is don't rename folder using `git mv dev-core core` just merge. Git will take care of everything.

In case you see two folder `dev-core` and `core` in your workspace that means git was not able to merge some files and they are kept at old location only. Just compare both files
`dev-core/projectX/file1` & `core/projectX/file1` using some comparing tool and fix the problem. Delete old file and you are done :)

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to see files with conflict markers, the conflict says

```
CONFLICT (rename/delete): core/projectX/path/to/java/file deleted in R1
    and renamed in HEAD.
```

which means there's a conflict because the file was renamed in your current
branch, while it was deleted altogether in R1.

You have to tell git how to resolve that conflict (i.e. do you want to rename
the file, or delete it?). Git left behind the renamed version of the file in
your working copy:

> Version HEAD of `core/projectX/path/to/java/file` left in tree.

If you do `git status`, you'll see something like this:

```
$ git status
On branch test
Your branch and 'origin/test' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        added by them:      core/projectX/path/to/java/file
```

You can either choose to keep the renamed version of the file by doing `git add <file>`,
or you can remove it by using `git rm <file>`. Then commit the changes. That's
how you resolve the merge conflict in this case.

Comment: I have both the branch checked out with me. I am running git merge R1 while staying on OPE branch. Am I merging right or wrong? After reading [this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) documentation my understanding is I am merging R1 into OPE.

Comment: @c2tarun you can't have two branches checked out at the same time. Please add ***your exact commands*** that you used to merge to your question.

Comment: I checked out OPE branch by:

`git checkout -b OPE origin/OPE`

Then I checked out R1 branch by:

`git checkout -b R1 origin/R1`

Then I switched back to OPE branch by:

`git checkout OPE`

Then I renamed root folder in OPE branch by:

`git mv dev-core core`

Then I tried to merged by following command:

`git merge R1`

Comment: @c2tarun Please edit that information into your question, as well as the command that you used to merge.

Comment: Sorry for posting incomplete info, I accidentally pressed return :(

Comment: Hi, can you please suggest anything?

Comment: @c2tarun sorry, I'm exhausted, I'll take another look tomorrow after I've gotten a full night's sleep.

Comment: No problem :) I'll wait.
Thanks

Comment: @c2tarun updated answer. It looks like you did the merge OK, you just need to figure out how you want to resolve the conflict (remove the file or keep the file).

Comment: I have a doubt, lets say if there is a file dev-core/projectX/file1. I made some changes to this file in my OPE branch and committed it. Now somebody else made some change in core/projectX/file1 in R1 branch. Now when I'll merge: Either git will merge both versions of file1 and will show me the conflict using <<< OR git will sense that file1 is renamed from dev-core/projectX/file1 to core/projectX/file1 and will let me keep my file and will discard the changes from R1 branch file
If I am correct then 2nd scenarios is my case and this might cause me loss of imp code Plz correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @c2tarun you should edit that information into your question, it will help other people help you to solve your problem. Is it possible to get a more specific example with a specific file? If you want, you can create a new test repo with just a file or two and test everything out to see how everything works. I'm sorry, but I don't have time to keep looking at this anymore, hopefully someone else can help you with the rest.

Comment: If anyone face this problem just do simple 
git merge 
instead of 
git mv 
and then 
git merge.

Comment: @c2tarun did that solve your problem? You're allowed to answer your own question.

Comment: Yup that solved my problem, instead of error in 600+ files now I am getting conflicts in around 50 files, that is manageable.